# REST-ful API URI Modeling approach

Tags: api, rest, uri, asp.net-web-api2, restful-url

I have a functional API endpoint

```
myapi.com/channels/costs
```

at present with the [GET] call implemented. This endpoint is now in production.

Now, this is for the all the customers in the USA. The same database used by this endpoint also has the relevant details for other countries.
I have requirement to incorporate the same logic/call for UK customers.

Should I use:
1. `myapi.com/uk/channels/costs` ?
2. (still use) `myapi.com/channels/costs` & then include a custom header to differentiate between USA and UK?

Is there a prescribed way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose you use the same URL with a query parameter (rather than a header) to specify the relevant country, defaulting to USA when not specified. This fits in with the RESTful style of the URI representing a resource that is being queried, and you're querying it slightly differently.